# Teams of children selected to end a war using nuclear weapons

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am looking for the title and the author of (I think) a short novel. I read it as a teenager 30 years ago and I think it is much older. Here is a very approximate summary.

Teams of children are put though a series of increasingly difficult tests. They have to obey the rules, but the team we follow sometimes circumvents these rules.

In the final test, one can see on a screen (?) numerous enemy ships, their home planet and a few allied ships. It is a schematic representation. The only rule is: do not use nuclear weapons. But the team does not see any other solution and use nuclear weapons. This destroys the enemies and their planet.

One then understands (or actually one understands gradually through the text) that these tests are real. Adults just refuse to be held responsible for a genocide.

Answer (score 51):

Could this be *Ender's Game* (or more specifically, the [short novelette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Game_(short_story)) on which it was based, from 1977 edition of Analog Magazine)?

Ender is explicitly told that he can't use his weapon on the planet.

> but does, because he's a cheeky little scamp.

Whereas in the full novel he's just told that he needs to make that decision himself.

> Ender shrugged. Maezr began his explanation. “Today’s game, boy, has a
> new element. We’re staging this battle around a planet. This will complicate things in two ways. The planet isn’t large, on the scale we’re
> using, but the ansible can’t detect anything on the other side of
> it—so there’s a blind spot. **Also, it’s against the rules to use
> weapons against the planet itself. All right?”**
>
> **“Why, don’t the weapons
> work against planets?” Maezr answered coldly. “There are rules of war,
> Ender, that apply even in training games.”**
>
> Ender shook his head
> slowly. “Can the planet attack?”
>
> Maezr looked nonplussed for a moment, then smiled. “I guess you’ll have to find that one out, boy. And one more thing. Today, Ender, your opponent isn’t the computer. I am your enemy today, and today I won’t be letting you off so easily. Today is a battle to the end. And I’ll use any means I can to defeat you.”

Comment: Beat me to it! Of course, in your quote, 
 Rackham telegraphs that the "rule" against using his weapon on a planet isn't really a "rule".

Comment: Ender doesn't use the weapon on the planet "because he's a cheeky little scamp;" he does it because he's *utterly exhausted* by the intense "training" and figures if he does something sooooo far beyond the pale that it makes him seem entirely unsuitable as a commander, they'll finally let him stop.

Comment: @MasonWheeler - I could change it to "because he's a wuss", if you'd prefer?

Comment: @Valorum It's not even that.  He's been pushed to his breaking point and is trying to manipulate them into throwing him out of the program, not realizing that they've been manipulating him into doing exactly this.

Comment: @MasonWheeler That's certainly true, but IMO Valorum's  "cheeky little scamp" is an acceptably cheeky little bit of whimsy for this site.

Comment: This could also be the sequel to the Ender's Game novel; *Ender's Shadow*, which is written from Bean's point of view.

Comment: I post the question as an unregistered user. I think I can't comment or confirm any answer. However I wanted to thank the contributors for their answer. This is really amazing! Thanks!

Comment: @bob1 Not if it was 30 years ago.  That was published in 1999, only 23 years ago.  (OP could be misremembering the timeframe, admittedly.)

Comment: As far as I remember, the weapons in "Enders Game" (any version), are never stated to be nuclear. They're just science-fictiony blaster thingys that work by unstated methods. As is common.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman True - I had forgotten the bit in OP about 30 y ago.

Comment: @FaheemMitha the big bad weapon in Ender's Game isn't nuclear, that's correct, but it's also not a blaster, it's the "Molecular Detachment Device" also referred to as "M.D Device" or "Doctor Device", it worked by creating a field where electrons couldn't be shared, that field then expanded but weakened, unless it met more molecules, where it would strengthen again. In the end, any matter close enough to the initial site would be gone and only a clump of iron molecules would be left over https://enderverse.fandom.com/wiki/Molecular_Disruption_Device

Comment: @MindSwipe I see. I remembered the "Doctor Device" bit, but didn't recall that it had been described in such detail.

Answer (score 27):

As has already been pointed out in the comments, this is likely Orson Scott Card's *[Ender's Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Game_(disambiguation))*, but the issue is that this story comes in two versions:

- A novelette that first appeared in *Analog* in 1977, and has later appeared [in many anthologies](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?50213)
- A 1985 novel-length work where Card added a bunch of framing for another novel he was working on, *[Speaker for the Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_for_the_Dead)*

In the novelette, Ender Wiggins [sic] is the youngest commander at the Battle School, where children are trained to fight mock battles against a nameless alien species at war with humanity. At first there are zero-g laser-tag like games but then it changes to VR ship-based space battles (commanded by Ender). After the climactic battle in which life on the enemy's home planet is wiped out, it is revealed that at some point the space battles became real. Ender actually wiped out a whole species.

The novel-length work contains extra stuff:

- Ender's last name is "Wiggin", not "Wiggins"
- There is a lot of material about Ender's early life, especially his siblings
- Ender's childhood bullies are quite harshly dealt with
- The novelette's nameless, faceless enemy is described in the novel as an insectoid hivemind species called the "Buggers"

Since you mentioned a short novel, my guess is it's the original 1977 novelette,  rather than the novel. But if you remember any of the later elements, it was the novel you read.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the work but I did a Google and the edit seemed to be correct, just wondering why did you reverse it?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot It may pertain to later books in the series (I stopped reading them after _Xenocide_), but not to the first one, and OP did not indicate they had read a series.

Comment: Ah gotcha, so we don't find out the true name of the species until a later book. I don't think it's necessarily a problem having that information in there but I see why you rejected the edit now.

Comment: I thought for sure they were called Formics in the novel. (but maybe in one of the many revised versions he's done over the years)

Comment: @NKCampbell I'll dig out my 1985 SFBC omnibus to check, but I really don't remember "Formics" being used. Not even in _Speaker for the Dead_.

Comment: @NKCampbell They were called "Formics" in later sequel works, such as the "Shadow" series, but not in the original book.

Comment: must be conflating the 'next book in series' list at the end which would have that word